# How to automatically run Laravel Pint on file save in VSCode?

Tags: laravel, pint

The [Laravel Pint docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pint#running-pint) specifies that you can run Pint by invoking the binary located in the vendor/bin directory like this:

```bash
./vendor/bin/pint
```

I would like to set this up in VSCode so that it automatically runs Pint when a specific file is saved. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use an extension that let's you run commands on file saves:

For example, you can use the [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) extension, then in the `settings.json` (preferably the local one), add the following command:

```json
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
  "commands": [
    {
      "match": "\\.php$",
      "cmd": "${workspaceFolder}/vendor/bin/pint ${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

This should invoke Pint only on the specific file that was saved.

Comment: Personal preference, but I would use the `--dirty` flag to avoid accidentally formatting files. `"${workspaceFolder/vendor/bin/pint --dirty ${file}"`